# Numerical Optimisation Question - Algorithm required to choose between products and scenarios

Tags: algorithm, optimization, numeric

I am trying to find the best algorithm for a situation where I have many different products, and 4 scenarios for each one (unrelated from each other) and their cost and revenue for that scenario. For example:

[image: Products and Scenarios]

I then want to find the optimal combination of scenarios so that it is returning the most revenue while being below a given cost constraint. E.g. i would want it to return:

[image]

I thought about creating every possible combination and calculating the cost and revenue of each (and just choosing max revenue where cost < £x) however there are far too many combinations as I have ~120 products and 5 scenarios (more combinations than there are atoms in the universe).

Does anybody know of any algorithms that could give a best guess of the optimal scenarios?

Many thanks

Comment: Question seems a little under-specified. For instance, what's with those zero cost/revenue entries?

Comment: The zero cost/revenue entries are simply another scenario where we do not spend anything on that product, and therefore don't get any revenue from that product (e.g. If we felt that the money is spent better elsewhere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a version of the famous operations research problem called "[The Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)".

In general, it's an "NP-Hard" problem, so there is no known way to efficiently AND optimally solve this. (And your version is even harder than the base problem.)

If you still want the optimal solution, you can use an integer programming optimizer/solver to solve the following model:

```
maximize sum( Revenue_ik * I_ik ) over all product-scenarios i,k  # maximize revenue

s.t.
sum( Cost_ik * I_ik ) over all product-scenarios i,k <= BUDGET  # Total cost should be lower than the budget
sum( I_ik ) over all scenarios k <= 1 for all products i   # Choose at most 1 scenario per product (we can make it equals if we *have* to choose)

I_ik in {0, 1} # Decision variables are binary: not choose or choose
```

That being said, there are other ways of finding a good solution. For instance, you can use heuristics and local-search methods like:

- Sort options by revenue/cost, greedily always choose the most cost-effective possible product x scenario.
- After getting the initial solution, check if there are improvements possible by swapping 2 products' scenarios at the same time. I.e., lowering one's cost while increasing other's cost.

Also, usually pseudo-polynomial algorithms exist to solve these kinds of problems. For your case, (unless I'm missing something) the following dynamic programming relation holds:

```
f(i, w) = max revenue possible using products 0...i, which costs at most w.

f(i, w) = max{ f(i-1, w) , f(i-1, w-Cost_ik) + Revenue_ik for each scenario k for product i }
f(-1, w) = 0 # base case
f(i, w) = -INFINITY if w < 0 # base case
```

If your maximum budget W is reasonable, this algorithm could find the optimal solution quite efficiently. For example, here is a Python snippet that optimally solves your current instance with a budget of 275:

```
cache = {}
chosen = {}

revenue = [[0, 200, 240, 250], [0, 207, 257, 398], [0, 115, 400, 350], [0, 240, 300, 340]]
cost = [[0, 30, 40, 60], [0, 35, 38, 70], [0, 110, 160, 240], [0, 80, 200, 350]]
scenarios = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
BUDGET = 275

def f(i, w):
    if w < 0:
        return -10000000
    if i == -1:
        return 0
    if (i, w) in cache:
        return cache[(i, w)]

    vals = [f(i - 1, w - cost[i][k]) + revenue[i][k] for k in scenarios[i]]
    max_val = max(vals)
    chosen_scenario = vals.index(max_val)
    chosen[(i, w)] = chosen_scenario
    cache[(i, w)] = max_val
    return max_val

print(f(3, BUDGET))
result = []
W = BUDGET
for i in reversed(range(len(scenarios))):
    chosen_scenario = chosen[(i, W)]
    result.append(chosen_scenario)
    W -= cost[i][chosen_scenario]

result.reverse()
print(result)
```

Output:

```
1038
[2, 3, 2, 0]
```

Max. revenue possible is 1038, choosing scenarios 2, 3, 2 and 0 for each product in order.